# How to replace a part of formula in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have 2 excel files:

file1: contain multi sheets named sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,...

file2: contain

1st column: the names of the sheets from file 1

2nd column: contain value from file one 
(=file path/ file name/ sheet name/ cell name)

I want to replace the "sheet name" with the value in the 1st column

is that possible without going through the file row by row ??

Comment: Have you tried using a helper column?

Comment: what did you mean by "helper column" ?

Comment: use another column to place a formula in that returns the value you need, then just copy that formula down. No need to go through each row manually then.

Comment: it's not a vlookup  I can't just copy the formula because if I did so the same value will be in all rows, I used " =file path/ file name/ sheet name/ cell name" formula

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, replacing NEW SHEET with your cell value

`=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",2))),"NEW SHEET",MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",3)),LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",2))))`